# how to get a name from a group by id in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have a table of customers groups and I would like to select the group's names (and another value called Notes) but group by doesn't allow me to do that even though the entire group has the same value of names and notes.

```
select cg.idCustomerGroup, 
       sum(case when c.type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as Children,
       sum(case when c.type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults,
       sum(case when c.type = 'senior' then 1 else 0 end) as Seniors
from CustomersGroups cg
   inner Join CustomersInGroup cig
      on cg.idCustomerGroup = cig.idCustomerGroup
   inner Join Customers c
      on c.idCustomer = cig.idCustomer
Group by cg.idCustomerGroup
```

Comment: And `Group by cg.idCustomerGroup, Notes` doesn't work? Can you add some sample table data, and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the  group's name and notes in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select cg.idCustomerGroup, cg.Name, cg.Notes,
       sum(case when c.type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as Children,
       sum(case when c.type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults,
       sum(case when c.type = 'senior' then 1 else 0 end) as Seniors
from CustomersGroups cg
   inner Join CustomersInGroup cig
      on cg.idCustomerGroup = cig.idCustomerGroup
   inner Join Customers c
      on c.idCustomer = cig.idCustomer
Group by cg.idCustomerGroup, cg.Name, cg.Notes
```

Comment: Or use `MAX(cg.Name) AS Name, MAX(cg.Notes) AS Notes` instead of including those fields in the `GROUP BY`...